# Request to reopen question 660409

Tags: support, status-declined, reopen-request

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/660409/what-happens-if-i-install-a-virtual-machine-additions-package-on-a-host-pc), which got marked as a duplicate. It originally contained two questions, of which the first was answered by both this question's and the target question's answers. However, the second was never answered. I have edited the question to only contain the second. Can it be reopened and answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't put multiple questions into one post. Simply post multiple questions.

If one of your questions simply is an extension of another question (like when you want a *general* answer instead of one specific to a single software/OS) then you can edit the other question and put a bounty on it to draw attention to this.

If an existing question is extended to cover more ground than it previously did, this is always a welcome improvement.

Comment: I know that now. Did you notice that I edited it to contain just one question?

Comment: @gparyani: From what I can tell, you removed the part of the question that the existing answers relate to. Which is very counter-productive and one of the reasons why posts should contain a single question to begin with. When drastically changing the content of your question, you make it less useful to future visitors. And having straight-forward questions with useful answers if one of the main goals of this platform.

Comment: I'm going to post another question and roll back the existing one. Is that OK?

Comment: @gparyani: Sounds great